# GET http://localhost:3000/api/products 404(not found) . i keep getting these errors of api/products 404 not found and images 404 not found

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been battling with these error for weeks now. Most of the images on homescreen do not load and it tells me

> localhost:3000/images/the image.jpg 404 not found

and also the product screen when i select a product to view details appears blank and i get the error

> localhost:3000/api/products 404 not found

ProductScreen

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';
import {useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import { detailsProduct } from '../actions/productActions';

function ProductScreen(props) {
    const {id} = useParams()
    console.log(id);

   const [qty, setQty ] = useState(1);
   const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails);
   const {product, loading, error} = productDetails;
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   ;
   
   

   useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(detailsProduct (id));
    return () => {
        //
    };
   }, [] )

    const handleAddToCart = () =>{
        props.history.push("/cart/" + id + "?qty=" + qty)
    }
    if (!product)
       return <></>

     return <div>
        <div className='back-to-result'>
            <Link to="/">Back to result</Link>
        </div>
        {loading?  <div> loading...</div>:
        error? <div>{error} </div>:
        (
            <><div className='details'>
                         <div className='details-image'>
                             <img src={product.image} alt={product}></img>
                         </div>
                         <div className='details-info'>
                             <ul>
                                 <li>
                                     <h4>{product.name}</h4>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                     {product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews} Reviews)
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                     Price: <b>{product.price}</b>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                     Description:
                                     <div>
                                         {product.description}
                                     </div>
                                 </li>
                             </ul>
                         </div>
                         <div className='details-action'>
                             <ul>
                                 <li>
                                     Price: {product.price}
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                     Status: {product.countInStock > 0 ? "In Stock": "Unavailable"}
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                     Qty:<select value={qty} onChange={(e) => {setQty(e.target.value)}}>
                                        {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map(x =>
                                            <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1} ></option>)}
                                     </select>
                                 </li>
                                 <li>
                                    
                                     {product.countInStock > 0 && <button onClick={handleAddToCart} className="button primary">Add to Cart</button> }
                                </li>
                             </ul>
                         </div>
                     </div><div className='details'></div></>
        )
        }
       
         </div>

}
export default ProductScreen;
```

HomeScreen

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux';    
import { listProducts } from '../actions/productActions';


function HomeScreen(props) {
    const productList = useSelector(state => state.productList);
    const {products, loading, error}  = productList;
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
       dispatch(listProducts());
        return () => {
            //
        };
    }, [])   

    return loading ? <div>Loading...</div>:
    error ? <div>{error}</div>:
    
     <ul className="products">
   
        {
            products && products.map((product) =>
            
                <li key={product._id}>
                    <div className="product">
                      <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}>
                         <img className="product-image" src={product.image} alt={product}></img>
                      </Link>
                      <div className="product-name">
                       <Link to={'/product/' + product._id}>{product.name}</Link>
                      </div>
                      <div className="product-brand">{product.brand}</div>
                      <div className="product-price">{product.price}</div>
                      <div className="product-rating">{product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews})</div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                )
        }
    </ul>
}
export default HomeScreen;



server.js

import express from 'express';
import data from './data';


const app = express();

app.get("/api/products/:id", (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.params.id;
    const product = data.products.find(x => x._id === productId);
    if (product)
       res.send(product);
    else
       res.status(404).send ({ msg : "Product Not Found."})  
});

app.get("/api/products", (req, res) => {
    res.send(data.products);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {console.log("Server started at https://localhost:5000") });


package.js

  "name": "frontend",
  "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "components": "^0.1.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.5",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.3",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "styled": "^1.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
    "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}

cart.action

import Axios from "axios";
import {CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM} from "../constants/cartConstants";

const addToCart = (productId, qty) => async (dispatch) =>{

    try {
        const {data} = await Axios.get("/api/products/" + productId);
        dispatch ({
            type: CART_ADD_ITEM, payload: {
                product: data._id,
                name: data.name,
                image: data.image,
                price: data.price,
                countInStock: data.countInStock,
                qty
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        
    }
}
const removeFromCart = (productId) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM, payload: productId});
}
export { addToCart, removeFromCart }
```

Comment: Hi there! Can you provide with more information about the dev server you are using? The issue you experience is not related to the code (likely), but to the configuration of your dev server

Comment: Please log provide.image in the console or tell us if it’s relative path or absolute. Is it a path to an image from the front project or a link to an image from the server. If it’s from the server and it’s absolute path you can access the image in browser by its url easily. Maybe the config of your server like nginx serves images in an specific way that you have to know that. Btw use product.image for alt instead of product.

Answer (score 0):

Your api server in on localhost:5000 and your front (react) is on localhost:3000. Your front must to make request to localhost:5000/api/...

I don't understand how you are providing images ¿`data.products`? ¿What are you iterating? If you iterate a array of 'data' ({_id: 1, path: "..."}) then you must to fix it, because you are providing a array... I mean these lines:

```
app.get("/api/products/:id", (req, res) => {
    const productId = req.params.id;
    const product = data.products.find(x => x._id === productId);
```

Anyways, this should be your backend:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'data')));

app.get('/api/products/:id', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'data', req.params.id + ".jpg"));
});


app.listen(5000, () => {console.log("Server started at https://localhost:5000") });
```

Comment: I am following a video tutorial from YouTube

Comment: It's ok. Make sure you follow up all steps and don't feel bad/fear of any question . Just try to provide max of code you think it's important for the question (not need the video link, maybe as source. But its not important)

Comment: By the way... Did you fix your error?

Comment: i dont have any folder named path

Comment: path is a library "https://nodejs.org/api/path.html" this is include by default maybe you have to use 'node:path'

Comment: not yet , still trying